# Керування дієслова повідомити

Tags: керування-відмінками

Натрапила на таку назву [статті](https://www.bbc.com/ukrainian/news-43920373): "Вільям і Кейт повідомили ім'я новонародженого сина". За [Академічним тлумачним словником (1970—1980)](http://sum.in.ua/s/povidomljaty), дієслово повідомити вимагає такі форми залежного слова чи речення:

> **ПОВІДОМЛЯТИ**, яю, яєш, недок., ПОВІДОМИТИ, млю, миш; мн. повідомлять; док., перех. Доводити до чийого-небудь відома; сповіщати.
>   Зробіть у книгарні наказ, щоб вони вислали.. всі належні мені
>   примірники, рівночасно повідомляючи мене, що й коли вислане (Михайло
>   Коцюбинський, III, 1956, 275); На порозі з'являється мати. Вона
>   повідомляє, як радісну таємницю, що прийшла кравчиха (Олесь Донченко,
>   V, 1957, 347); Моє діло.. повідомити його точно про справи для нього
>   цікаві (Леся Українка, V, 1956, 146); Задихаючись й зупиняючися,
>   розказала [Катерина] все, що чула зараз вдома. І просила бігти,.. аби
>   повідомити, аби випередити біду (Гнат Хоткевич, II, 1966, 236); А ще
>   повідомив Вижлінський, що завтра оголосять нові податки селу
>   (Володимир Гжицький, Опришки, 1962, 14);
>
> //  Доповідати, робити донесення про що-небудь. Наполеон наказав
>   ад'ютантові негайно повернутись до маршала Мюрата і щогодини
>   повідомляти про хід операції (Панас Кочура, Золота грамота, 1960,
>   362); — Генерал наказав повідомити, що в Севастополі оголошено великий
>   збір (Василь Кучер, Чорноморці, 1956, 29);
>
> //  Розповідати про
>   що-небудь. Приміряючи свої чоботи, Кармазин спокійно повідомляв
>   Сагайді, що одержав оце трохи поповнення, молодих, необстріляних
>   (Олесь Гончар, III, 1959, 331);
>
> //  Казати що-небудь. Саїд Алі спинився й,
>   помовчавши, зниженим голосом, повідомив: — Упав до того, що й
>   координати цієї Суламіф вивчив (Іван Ле, Міжгір'я, 1953, 42).

У наведених прикладах видно, що у знахідному чи давальному відмінку при дієслові знаходиться назва, що позначає адресата повідомлення, а зміст повідомлення має форму місцевого - про кого?, про що? Але, здається, існує нормативний вислів *повідомляти новину*. То чи правильно побудоване речення у статті?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вислів **повідомити новину** існує помилково. Правильний варіант **повідомити про новину**. У прикладі з питання повинно бути  "Вільям і Кейт назвали ім'я новонародженого сина".

Дієслово **повідомляти** за значенням **доводити до чийого-небудь відома** - перехідне, отже не потребує прийменника для керування. Але в такому випадку дієслово має керувати іменником на позначення особи, а не предметним значенням.

**Повідомляти** в значенні **розповідати** стає неперехідним і вимагає прийменника для приєднання іменників **новина** чи **ім'я**, що не виступають тут обєктом дії.

> [Неперехідні дієслова](http://pidruchniki.com/68686/dokumentoznavstvo/kategoriya_perehidnostineperehidnosti) вживаються самостійно (без залежної
>   відмінкової форми) або керують будь-якою відмінковою формою іменника з
>   прийменником чи без прийменника, крім знахідного прямого об'єкта.